# What's the proper way of creating a MySQL table for <select> field which is optional?

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I always use **auto_increment** when making tables. Right now I'm trying to make a table for an html `<select>` field but the problem is that it's set to optional so the first `<option>...</option>` will have to have a value of `0`. Does that mean that when I structure the table the first auto_increment will have to start at 0 as well? Is that even valid?

**Edit:** Thanks for your comments. I'll be using the table in some `INNER JOIN` statement so the primary key is a foreign key in some other table. What will the value of the foreign key be if the user doesn't opt to answer the  field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use auto_increment if you need to start counting at 0 (not valid).

You could, however, hard-code your default `<option>` in HTML.

Comment: I thought about this too. But if the user doesn't answer the `<select>` field (value is 0), what then will be the value of the table which uses this as a foreign key? I'm guessing `NULL` but doesn't NULL equate to `0` if the column is set to INT?

Comment: You could just ignore the "part" in your queries if the user decides to not use your select. What back-end language are you using? In PHP it would be like: `if($_POST['select'] == 0) // do nothing/alternative query`

Comment: Yup, PHP. If I evade it with a conditional, what of the foreign key then? Set it to `NULL`?

Comment: I don't know what you are going to achieve. Why are you using `INNER JOIN`? Use `LEFT JOIN` or `RIGHT JOIN` and MySQL will populate the field with NULL for you.

Comment: That's true. I guess I'll stick with inserting a `0` then since a blank value gets translated to 0 anyway: `<option value="0">- choose -</option>`.

Comment: Be careful, if you do `INSERT INTO` and use 0 as value for the auto_increment coloum MySQL will create a new ID for you.

Comment: That's ok. The `0` will be for the foreign key while the primary key will be left at auto_increment (not 0).

Answer (score 0):

They don't really have anything to do with each other. You could do this in many ways. You could create a table just for those options, then you can choose whatever primary key you like, auto_increment or not. When you write your html, you can just use the `selected` tag to tell which of the alternatives are default.

```
<option value="x" selected="selected">x</option>
```

It all depends on you database design overall though, if you're going to have a separate table for these options or not.

Comment: How would you design it? If I may ask. I guess I *shouldn't* put a `NOT NULL` in the foreign key then like so: `columnname INT(9)`. Inserting a blank string as the value gets converted to a `0`, while inserting `NULL` stays as NULL. What would you use, `0` or `NULL`?

Comment: If it was possible for the list to grow according to user input, I'd use something liks <option value="PK of table">Name column of table</option> I don't see why you worry about 0's and what not. Just present the contents of the table and let the first selected option be empty. <option value="" selected="selected">Select one...</option> The user is going to use the select list anyway, right?

Comment: Oh, and please upvote my answer if it was useful. I'm one of those who actually care and get motivated by upvotes :)